# Valid proof for integral of $1/(x^2+a^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to prove some integral table formulae and had a concern over my proof of the following formula:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\;dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$$

Claim:

$$\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{2k}\hspace{5mm}\forall\;x\in(-a,a)$$

Proof:

$$\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{a^4}+\frac{x^4}{a^6}-\frac{x^6}{a^8}+\dots$$

$$\implies 1=(x^2+a^2)\left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{a^4}+\frac{x^4}{a^6}-\frac{x^6}{a^8}+\dots\right)$$

$$\implies 1=\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^4}{a^4}+\frac{x^6}{a^6}-\frac{x^8}{a^8}+\dots\right)+\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{x^4}{a^4}-\frac{x^6}{a^6}+\dots\right)$$

$$\implies 1=1\hspace{5mm}\forall\;x\in(-a,a)$$

My proof then uses the following:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\;dx=\frac{1}{a^2}\int\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{2k}\;dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$$

My concern is that this isn't a valid proof since the radius of convergence of arctangent's Taylor Series is finite. I'm 7 years removed from taking calculus so I'm admittedly forgetful of the fine details on this. Could someone explain if this is a valid approach or, if not, why?

Comment: It's a decent concern.  Must you prove it by power series?

Comment: Also, it's not a valid proof since you assume the conclusion then deduce a triviality ($1=1$).

Comment: @Randall Could you explain? All I did was rewrite the integrand using a generating series and then integrated it to derive the formula

Comment: @Randall It does work if the deductions are equivalencies, which they should be as long as the series converges absolutely.

Comment: So have I only shown this is valid over $(-1,1)$ and not $\mathbb R$ since it's only convergent there?

Comment: @LanierFreeman $(-a,a)$ actually. And yes, this proof only shows validity for $x\in (-a,a)$.

Comment: For $x < -a$ and $x > a$, the substitution $x\rightarrow a^2/x$ gives you the same integral negated, but now with $x \in (-a,a)$. Then you just have to show that $-\arctan(a/x)$ and $\arctan(x/a)$ differ by a constant and verify you can choose the constants in the three regions such that the whole function is continuous at $x = \pm a$.

Comment: It is best **not** to arrange a proof as: start with what you want to prove, and deduce from it something true.  For the final proof reverse the steps:  Start with something true and deduce what you want to prove.

Comment: @GEdgar Forgive me, but I'm not entirely sure where I'm doing that.  The process was 1) Use a generating series to rewrite the integrand then 2) integrate and show the result is a variant of the Taylor Series for arctangent. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: @LanierFreeman: In the very last equality, how do you know what the power series for the arctan function is? Usually this is *proved* by integrating the power series for $1/(1+x^2)$, so to avoid your proof becoming circular you would need to give some *other* argument for why arctan has that expansion.

Comment: @HansLundmark Ah I see, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual attack for this integral is to "pull a rabbit out of a hat":  most books will say something like

> Hey, remember back in Chapter 4 where we used the inverse function theorem to prove that
> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}?$$
> Well!  This automatically tells us that
> $$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \arctan(x) + C.$$
> Then make a change of variables to deal with
> $$ \int \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2} \,\mathrm{d}x. $$
> Isn't that **easy**?!

However, another approach is a trigonometric substitution:  to visualize this, take $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}$ to be the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs of length $a$ and $x$, and take $\theta$ to be the angle adjacent to the side of length $a$.

[image]

Then $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}
\implies
\frac{1}{x^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} \cos(\theta)^2.$$
From the same triangle, $\tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{a}$, from which it follows that
$$ \sec(\theta)^2 \,\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{1}{a} \,\mathrm{d}x
\implies \mathrm{d}x = a \sec(\theta)^2 \,\mathrm{d}\theta. $$
Making the change of variables,
$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int \frac{1}{a^2} \cos(\theta)^2 \cdot a \sec(\theta)^2 \,\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{1}{a} \int \,\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\theta}{a} + C.
$$
Recall that $\tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{a}$, which implies that $\theta = \arctan(\frac{x}{a}). $  Therefore
$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{a} \arctan\!\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + C.$$
One has to be a little careful to ensure that the hypotheses of the change of variables ($u$-substitution; integration by substitution) is justified, but this can be done.

---

If you want to approach the problem using power series, there are a couple of things which need to be done.  First, you seem to be assuming the conclusion from the start.  However, it is possible to obtain a power series expansion for
$$ \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2} $$
without assuming it from the start, so I'll skip this step.<sup>[1]</sup>  I will also assume that the power series expansion of $\arctan$ is already known—there are ways of doing this which *aren't* circular.

To finish this off, we can apply a result from complex analysis.  The theorem needed is the identity theorem:

> **Theorem:**  Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two complex functions which are defined on some domain $D$, $S\subset D$ has an accumulation point, and $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in S$.  Then $f^{(n)}(z) = g^{(n)}(z)$ for all $z \in D$.

Take
$$ f(z) = \int \frac{1}{z^2 + a^2} \,\mathrm{d}z
\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(z) = \frac{1}{a} \arctan\!\left(\frac{z}{a}\right), $$
both of which are entire functions (they are complex differentiable on all of $\mathbb{C}$).<sup>[2]</sup>

The argument presented in the question asserts that $f(z) = g(z)$ for any value of $z$ which falls into the disk of convergence for the power series.  This disk has lots of accumulation points, so take that to be the set $S$ in the identity theorem.

From this, it follows that the claimed identity holds on all of $\mathbb{C}$, which implies that it holds on $\mathbb{R}$ (since $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$).

---

[1] The usual approach is to start with the fact that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} y^k = \frac{1}{1-y} $$
on the interval or disk of convergence, and then monkey around with the variables a little, e.g. take $y = -x^2/a^2$ or something similar.

[2] Technically, $f$ is an equivalence class of functions—choose the representative with $C = 0$, and don't worry too much about it.  Or take derivatives on both sides of the equation and take advantage of the uniqueness of antiderivatives up to an additive constant at the end.

Comment: In fairness, basically every elementary antiderivative pulls the rabbit out of the hat at some point.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Of course. That doesn't mean that they *have* to. :P

Comment: Phenomenal detail here--thank you so much!

Comment: @LanierFreeman I should clarify that I really do think that the "pull a rabbit out of a hat" argument is probably the "right" way to do things.  It is the most elementary approach, using the fewest high-powered tools.  But it can be fun to try to do things in non-standard kinds of ways.

Comment: "Pulling a rabbit out of a hat" is a great way of putting it. Most calculus books I've used do something similar when showing the derivative of $1/x$ is $ln(x)$ by using a theorem about differentiating a composition of inverses. I wrote a direct proof from the difference quotient that uses the limit definition of $e$, but it's not exactly simple for a calc student to grasp imo

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144341/discussion-on-answer-by-xander-henderson-valid-proof-for-integral-of-1-x2a2); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

It’s valid for $|x|\leq 1$ due to the uniform convergence of the Taylor series you obtain after integrating to arctan, but not outside this interval and has to do with not being able to pull that sum outside the integral on this region. I can give you a simpler way to integrate this if you’d like?

Comment: Would you mind leaving it as a hint so I can try it myself?

Comment: I guess it’s only a hint if you beforehand the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, but it would be to make the simple change of coordinates $u=x/a$.

Comment: I can work from that-- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I call an almost immediate antiderivative, based on the fact that if $\;\int f(x)\,dx = F(x)\;$ , then we can conclude that $\;\int f(g(x)) g'(x)\,dx = F(g(x))\;$, which of course it's just the basis of substitution, and thus:

$$\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}=\frac1a\int\frac{\frac1adx}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}=\frac1a\int\frac{d\left(\frac xa\right)}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}=\frac1a\arctan\frac xa+C$$